# Parse Server Phone Login - Account already exists for this username

Tags: node.js, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I am migrating an iOS app to swift 3 and Parse Server 2.3 and some of the code seems not to work anymore. 
Users can signup and login on the app via their phone number and an OTP.

Issue: if a user login with a used phone number, the server answers with "Account already exists for this username." wheres I would like to log him anyway.

Edited for security

Answer (score 0):

I just had to update parse-server to 2.3.3 to solve the issue